# Google Sheets, SUMIF function gives: "Error, argument must be a range" for summing up rows conditionally on tags

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs

[Function that is erroring, references the other image/sheet below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcJOl.png)

[This is the referenced image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Dx5R.png)

I have a sheet with a list of expenses, prices, and associated "tags" which are the categories of the expenditure. Note that there can be multiple categories per expenditure, in which case the price should be included in full in all of them.

I have another sheet which uses links to the first sheet, and this sheet contains the summation logic using a SUMIF, each category label (in column A), etc, as shown in the first image. This function used to work, however I recently returned to the sheet and it is erroring. Note that removing the recent additions did not seem to fix the problem. As a beginner, I am completely lost in how to fix this error. Also note that the links were shortened for the screenshot as to not dox my public sheets.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

I have tried updating the links, and modifying the logic (although I have no clue what I'm doing so that didn't work). Nothing helped.

Comment: Welcome. Please read [ask], [edit] your question accordingly and let us know

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Λ,importrange("1svG7","Itemized Expenses!A:F"),
    {"Total Tag Price";map(A3:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,sum(ifna(filter(index(Λ,,3),search(Σ,index(Λ,,6))))))))})
```